# WebApi POST returns 404 on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, appharbor

I have a Asp.net WebAPI service that is hosted on AppHarbor which throws 404 error on POST requests. The MVC 4 controller's POST works perfectly though that is hosted in the same virtual dir.

The same WebApi works on localhost. I tried below options with no luck:

```
<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
   </modules>
   <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

I also tried setting up action based URL to check if that works, but no luck. I have even decorated the method with:

```
 [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
```

Would there be anything that needs to be added to web.config or any authentication setting that I am missing.

Comment: Do other WebApi methods based on `GET`'s (for example) work?

Comment: Hmm, I have WebAPI setup in my test site on AH and it is working... I wonder what could be different. Did you setup WebAPI using Nuget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was because of a database problem. I over looked the default try..catch which was returning a

```
HttpStatusCode.NotFound (404)
```

instead of a 500 error code. Its up and running now.